# Using common codebase between Google Chrome and v8 embedded in C++ app

Tags: javascript, embed, webgl, requirejs, v8

I'm working on a WebGL scene graph library as a hobby project. I now want run my code in v8 embedded in a C++ app, exposing OpenGL 4.3 to the JavaScript code.

I'm using require.js in my WebGL code now, will that continue to work when I run from v8 embedded? Are there other alternatives that would work both when running in Chrome and the C++ app?

Apart from handling both WebGL and OpenGL 4.3, are there any other problems I should be aware of?

Comment: Just embed Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) itself?